# Minimum eigenvalue of sum of outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a matrix defined as,

$$M = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_k\\
y_k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x^{\intercal}_k & y^{\intercal}_k
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $x_k \in \mathbb R^p, y_k \in \mathbb R^q$. What can we say about the minimum eigen value of $M$ in terms of minimum eigen values of $$M_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x^{\intercal}_k
\end{bmatrix},
M_2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y^{\intercal}_k
\end{bmatrix}$$

Also $M,M_!,M_2$ is full rank.

Comment: A more compact version would be to write $M:=\begin{pmatrix}XX^T&XY^T\\YX^T&YY^T\end{pmatrix}$ and the other matrices $XX^T$ and $YY^T$, where $X$ resp. $Y$, is the matrix with columns $x_k$, resp. $y_k$.

Comment: In such questions, a technique that can be attempted is to characterize eigenvalues through quadratic form $(A B)^T M^T \binom{A}{B}=(AX+BY)^T(AX+BY)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint that I think a good way to reach the final result.

First of all, a more compact version of matrix $M$ is

$$M:=\begin{pmatrix}XX^T&XY^T\\YX^T&YY^T\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

where $M_1:=XX^T$ and $M_2=YY^T$ (your notations).

A classical way to work on the eigenvalues is to associate the given matrix to a quadratic form, that happen to be factorized in a nice way:

$$(A B)^T M^T \binom{A}{B}=(AX+BY)^T(AX+BY)\tag{2}$$

(please note that I have taken $M^T$ instead of $M$ ; this doesn't matter because $M$ and $M^T$ have the same eigenvalues).

The fact that $Y$ in particular is invertible gives rise to a simplification by factorizing (2) in the following way:

$$((AXY^{-1}+B)Y)^T(AXY^{-1}+B)Y)=Y^T(AZ+B)^T(AZ+B)Y \tag{3}$$

with $Z$ defined by $Z:=XY^{-1}$.

We are now with a new, simpler, quadratic expression

$$Q:=(AZ+B)^T(AZ+B)=Z^T(A^TA)Z+...$$

which becomes a classical issue.

Sorry, no more time at present...

Comment: Do complete your answer when you get time. I am not aware of this technique.

Comment: This can be considered in the light of **Rayleigh quotients** technique, which is sometimes more widely known. Besides, I think that eigenvalues of $XY^{-1}$ play definitely an important rôle.